# how to pass java encoding class to a method

Tags: java

I need to pass java encoded class to a method, the class method takes encoding as a parameter, like this

```
frombytes(bytes[] b, encoding encoding)
```

I have no idea how to pass it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume encoding is a user defined class.

if you need to pass an object of type encoding to the above method,

```
encoding encodingObj = new encodingObj(); // assuming it has a no arg constructor
 byte[] byteObj = new byte[10];
 //initialize byte array

 frombytes(byteObj,encodingObj)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but encoding is not a user defined class. It is a java language class. Please see  [link](http://www.javadocs.com/docs/org.postgresql/postgresql/9.2-1002-jdbc4/org/postgresql/core/Encoding.java).Further this frombytes method will return a map.

Comment: okay but it should be Encoding i guess. not encoding. and bytes[] should be byte[]

Answer (score 0):

you would just call:

```
frombytes(b, encoding);
```

Answer (score 0):

Abstract way to pass encoding class:

```
  import java.nio.charset.Charset;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            get(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            frombytes("Hello".getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }
    public static void get(Charset charset){
            System.out.println(charset);
    }

    public static void frombytes(bytes[] b, Charset encoding){
            System.out.println(charset);
    }
```